# UISearchController crash on iOS13

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller, ios13

Working on iOS12 and prior, but crashes on iOS13 with this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UISearchController's control over its search bar has been destroyed. Please use the search bar provided by the UISearchController. searchController = <AdvancedSearchController: 0x7fbd9d224a00>, searchBar = <TDSearchBar: 0x7fbd9b768480; baseClass = UISearchBar; frame = (0 0; 1024 50); text = ''; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002791770>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ef9be0>>'
```

How con i solve? What does this exception mean?

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e296c3e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e104de0 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e296a7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000011fa6e6b0 -[UISearchController _animatorForBarPresentationStyle:dismissing:] + 185
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011fa6eb24 -[UISearchController animationControllerForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController:] + 34
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a03a0 -[UIViewController _customAnimatorForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController:] + 154
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a4534 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4472
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a6d1b __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 98
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a7233 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 511
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a6c79 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 187
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011f3a6ee0 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. You cannot neither subclass UISearchBar in UISearchController...at least in beta 3.

Comment: I was wondering if you've tried again with iOS 13/13.1 release versions? I was going to try writing a custom `UISearchBar` subclass myself until I saw this question/answer. Thanks!

Comment: Answering my own comment: I am able to subclass both UISearchBar and UISearchController in iOS 13.0 and 13.1